# Regex match multiple results between the same delimiters

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Very poor title - feel free to update it if you feel you can help

I'm trying to return a list

`[<str1>, <str2>,...,<strX>]`

in the following string:

'`%%<str1>%%_Anything_Can_Be_Here_%%<str2>%%`'

The following code works, but if the number of '`%%`'s in the line is greater than 2, it takes everything between the first and last set of '`%%`'.

```
>>> import re
>>> str = '%%nas_ip_address%%'
>>> re.match('%%(.*)%%', str, re.DOTALL).group(1)
'nas_ip_address'


>>> str = '%%nas_ip_address%%:/vx/%%sfs_storage_pool%%'
>>> re.match('%%(.*)%%', str, re.DOTALL).group(1)
'nas_ip_address%%:/vx/%%sfs_storage_pool'
>>> re.match('%%(.*)%%', str, re.DOTALL).groups()
('nas_ip_address%%:/vx/%%sfs_storage_pool',)
```

Is there a way to somehow extract `['nas_ip_address', 'sfs_storage_pool']` from the string using regex? I'm looking to parse a very large file however the performance is not an issue as it's not for production

Comment: `(%{2,})(.*?)\1`? Capture group 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `re.findall()` if you want to match multiple results in the same string

Try this:

```
import re
str = '%%nas_ip_address%%:/vx/%%sfs_storage_pool%%'
re.findall('%%(.*?)%%', str, re.DOTALL)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `*` is greedy by default, which means it will consume everything till the end, then backtrack one character at a time until finding the closest `%%`, close to the end of string then.

Two options to prevent it:

1. use lazy quantifier `*?`
2. even better if no risk of an occuring `%` in between, add contrast and use a negated character class `[^%]*`.